# Which is the better estimator for standard deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation, convergence, unbiased-estimator, estimators

Let $X_i \sim^{\textrm{iid}} N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. If I have measured $n$ values of $\textrm{std}(X_i)$ as $\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_n$, then what is the better estimator for $\sigma$:

$$\hat{\sigma}_1 = \dfrac{\sigma_1+\cdots+\sigma_n}{n}$$

Or

$$\hat{\sigma}_2 = \sqrt{\dfrac{\sigma_1^2+\cdots+\sigma_n^2}{n}}$$

These are both unbiased estimators, so I figure the answer lies in determining their convergence properties, although I'm unsure how to do this.

Comment: Do you mean that you take $k$ observations from a normal distribution and calculate $\hat{\sigma}_1$, then take another $k$ observations from the same normal distribution and calculate $\hat{\sigma}_2$, all the way until you take $k$ observations from that same normal distribution and calculate $\hat{\sigma}_n$?

PS: Sample standard deviation itself is a biased estimator of population standard deviation. (I find this fact amazing.) I'm skeptical that you've given unbiased estimators. Given that sample standard deviation is biased, why do you think that both of yours are unbiased?

Comment: @Dave I'm not 100% as to how the $\sigma_i$ were calculated, so I have to assume they are not biased. Given that, then I have the above 2 estimators that I can easily show would be unbiased. Obviously this would lead to also having a general unbiased estimator $\hat{\sigma}_k = \Big(\dfrac{\sigma_1^k +\cdots+\sigma_n^k}{n}\Big)^{1/k}$, which leads me to assume the $k=1$ case is optimal

Comment: The typical formula for a sample standard deviation is a BIASED estimator of the population standard deviation. Also, unless we know what $\sigma_1,\dots ,\sigma_n$ mean, we cannot proceed with the question.

Comment: You need to clarify whether $\sigma_i$ is exact parameter value (usual notation) or estimate from sample (for which usual notation would be $S_i.)$.